# Embed json string in amchart chart?

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I'm trying to embed some `json` into my amcharts. This is the `javascript` code in the `html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "imagesSettings": {
    "rollOverColor": "#089282",
    "rollOverScale": 1,
    "selectedScale": 0.5,
    "selectedColor": "#089282",
    "color": "#13564e",
    "selectable": false,
    "bringForwardOnHover": false
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "color": "#D3D3D3",
    "autoZoom": true
  },  
  "data": {
    "map": "puertoRicoHigh"
  },
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "http://OurServer/Service1.svc/GetLocations",
    "format": "json",
    "showErrors": true,
    "postProcess": function(data, config, map) {
      // create a new dataProvider
      var mapData = map.data;

      // init images array
      if (mapData.images === undefined)
        mapData.images = [];

      // create images out of loaded data
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var image = data[i];
        image.type = "circle";
        mapData.images.push(image);
      }
      return mapData;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

And this is what the `json` looks like: `[{"title":"Site1","latitude":18.37,"longitude":-67.18},{"title":"Site2","latitude":18.20,"longitude":-65.80}]`

I've been trying to embed this `json` into the code, but I'm having trouble doing so.

I tried using `dataprovider` instead of `dataloader` since it's not an http request, but I know I'm missing something:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "imagesSettings": {
    "rollOverColor": "#089282",
    "rollOverScale": 1,
    "selectedScale": 0.5,
    "selectedColor": "#089282",
    "color": "#13564e",
    "selectable": false,
    "bringForwardOnHover": false
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "color": "#D3D3D3",
    "autoZoom": true
  },  
  "data": {
    "map": "puertoRicoHigh"
  },
    "dataProvider": [{"title":"Site1","latitude":18.3764,"longitude":-67.1819},{"title":"Site2","latitude":18.2001,"longitude":-65.8081}],  
    "postProcess": function(data, config, map) {
      // create a new dataProvider
      var mapData = map.data;

      // init images array
      if (mapData.images === undefined)
        mapData.images = [];

      // create images out of loaded data
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var image = data[i];
        image.type = "circle";
        mapData.images.push(image);
      }
      return mapData;
    }  
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The map `dataProvider` is an [object](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapData), not an array, whose structure is demonstrated on the [map demos on the AmCharts website](http://www.amcharts.com/demos). Since your JSON is basically an array of [map images](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapImage), going by the postProcess method, you can restructure your `dataProvider` like so, adding `type: "circle"` to each image and skipping the need for any further processing:

```
dataProvider: {
  map: "puertoRicoHigh",
  images: [
    {"title":"Site1","latitude":18.3764,"longitude":-67.1819, "type": "circle"},
    {"title":"Site2","latitude":18.2001,"longitude":-65.8081, "type": "circle"}
  ]
}
```

Demo:

```js
AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "imagesSettings": {
    "rollOverColor": "#089282",
    "rollOverScale": 1,
    "selectedScale": 0.5,
    "selectedColor": "#089282",
    "color": "#13564e",
    "selectable": false,
    "bringForwardOnHover": false
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "color": "#D3D3D3",
    "autoZoom": true
  },
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "puertoRicoHigh",
    "images": [{
        "title": "Site1",
        "latitude": 18.3764,
        "longitude": -67.1819,
        "type": "circle"
      },
      {
        "title": "Site2",
        "latitude": 18.2001,
        "longitude": -65.8081,
        "type": "circle"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/puertoRicoHigh.js"></script>
<div id="mapdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One of the reasons I wanted to embed it as `json` is so that I could post self-contained questions in SO that included an actual `json` string.

Comment: So I'm still confused - are you trying to make it work through the dataloader plugin or directly through the dataProvider?